# Get Windows Service Pack Version from Java Applet?

Tags: windows, applet, java

I am writing a Java Applet. When run on Windows, I need to be able to get the clients OS version, e.g. Windows XP SP3 or Windows 2000 SP4.

I can currently use the following:

```
String os_name    = System.getProperty( "os.name" );
String os_version = System.getProperty( "os.version" );

System.out.println( "Running on " + os_name + "(" + os_version + ")" );
```

And it will output something like "Running on Windows 2000 (5.0)" which is great but I need to be able to get the service pack version too.

Anybody know how I can get the underlying service pack version of a Windows machine from within a Java applet? (Without throwing an AccessControlException, or ideally without having to self sign the applet).

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: PiPeep: just marked your answer as correct, enjoy your new 200 points! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can self-sign your java applet:

(stolen from: http://www.captain.at/programming/java/)

> Make the certificate:
>
> ```
> keytool -export -alias yourkey -file yourcert.crt
> ```
>
> Now we have to sign the applet:
>
> Just make a *.bat file including this:
>
> ```
> javac yourapplet.java
> jar cvf yourapplet.jar yourapplet.class
> jarsigner yourapplet.jar yourkey
> ```
>
> The batch-file compiles the applet,
>   makes a jar-archive and signs the
>   jar-file.
>
> The HTML-code to display the applet:
>
> ```
> <applet code="yourapplet.class" archive="yourapplet.jar" width="600"
> ```
>
> height="500">
>
> Now we are done! The applet is signed
>   and if the user accepts the
>   certificate, the applet is allowed to
>   access local files. If the user
>   doesn't agree, you get a
>   `java.security.AccessControlException`.

So, as long as you don't mind about this little dialog box...

Comment: Thanks PiPeep, this would work if I was to use the "sun.os.patch.level" property to get the Service Pack version. Ideally I would prefer not to access this property and thus not have to not sign the applet. If their is no other way this answer is correct.

Answer (score 3):

i think you can get it using the 'sun.os.patch.level' property:

```
String os_sp = System.getProperty( "sun.os.patch.level" );
```

Comment: Thanks, just tried. It works when used in a application but throws an AccessControlException when used from an applet. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

To get the OS version (major, minor, build, service pack) you can use JNA [Documentation Here](http://today.java.net/article/2009/11/11/simplify-native-code-access-jna) and any number of the windows libraries (version.dll, kernel32.dll, user32.dll, etc).  I based my project on Daniel Doubrovkine's project [Operating System and Hardware Information](http://oshi.codeplex.com/).  His project will also query the hardware, which I didn't need.  The nice thing is it will also allow you to read/write to the registry.

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Advapi32Util;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Win32Exception;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT.OSVERSIONINFOEX;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinReg;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;

/**
 *
 * @author geverding
 */
public class OSVersionInfo {

    private OSVERSIONINFOEX versionInfo;
    private static OSVersionInfo instance = new OSVersionInfo();

    public static OSVersionInfo Istance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public OSVersionInfo() {
        versionInfo = new OSVERSIONINFOEX();
        if (!Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetVersionEx(versionInfo))
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetLastError());
        }
    }

    public int getMajor() {
        return versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue();
    }

    public int getMinor() {
        return versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue();
    }

    public int getBuild() {
        return versionInfo.dwBuildNumber.intValue();

    }

    public String getServicePack() {
        return Native.toString(versionInfo.szCSDVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String version = null;

        if (versionInfo.dwPlatformId.intValue() == WinNT.VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_NT)
        {
            // 7
            if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 6
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 1
                    && versionInfo.wProductType == WinNT.VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
            {
                version = "7";
            } // Server 2008 R2
            else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 6
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 1
                    && versionInfo.wProductType != WinNT.VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
            {
                version = "Server 2008 R2";
            } // Server 2008
            else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 6
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 0
                    && versionInfo.wProductType != WinNT.VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
            {
                version = "Server 2008";
            } // Vista
            else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 6
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 0
                    && versionInfo.wProductType == WinNT.VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
            {
                version = "Vista";
            } // Server 2003
            else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 5
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 2
                    && versionInfo.wProductType != WinNT.VER_NT_WORKSTATION
                    && User32.INSTANCE.GetSystemMetrics(WinUser.SM_SERVERR2) != 0)
            {
                version = "Server 2003";
            } // Server 2003 R2
            else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 5
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 2
                    && versionInfo.wProductType != WinNT.VER_NT_WORKSTATION
                    && User32.INSTANCE.GetSystemMetrics(WinUser.SM_SERVERR2) == 0)
            {
                version = "Server 2003 R2";
            } // XP 64 bit
            else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 5
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 2
                    && versionInfo.wProductType == WinNT.VER_NT_WORKSTATION)
            {
                version = "XP";
            } // XP 32 bit
            else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 5
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 1)
            {
                version = "XP";
            } // 2000
            else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 5
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 0)
            {
                version = "2000";
            } // Windows NT
            else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 4)
            {
                version = "NT 4";

                if ("Service Pack 6".equals(Native.toString(versionInfo.szCSDVersion)))
                {
                    if (Advapi32Util.registryKeyExists(WinReg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\WindowsNT\\CurrentVersion\\Hotfix\\Q246009"))
                    {

                        return "NT4 SP6a";
                    }
                }

            } else
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Windows NT version: "
                        + versionInfo.toString());
            }

            if (versionInfo.wServicePackMajor.intValue() > 0)
            {
                version = version + " SP" + versionInfo.wServicePackMajor.intValue();
            }

        } else if (versionInfo.dwPlatformId.intValue() == WinNT.VER_PLATFORM_WIN32_WINDOWS)
        {
            if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 4
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 90)
            {
                version = "ME";
            } else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 4
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 10)
            {
                if (versionInfo.szCSDVersion[1] == 'A')
                {
                    version = "98 SE";
                } else
                {
                    version = "98";
                }
            } else if (versionInfo.dwMajorVersion.intValue() == 4
                    && versionInfo.dwMinorVersion.intValue() == 0)
            {
                if (versionInfo.szCSDVersion[1] == 'C' || versionInfo.szCSDVersion[1] == 'B')
                {
                    version = "95 OSR2";
                } else
                {
                    version = "95";
                }
            } else
            {
                throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Windows 9x version: "
                        + versionInfo.toString());
            }
        } else
        {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unsupported Windows platform: "
                    + versionInfo.toString());
        }

        return version;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put simply you can't get the value of the `sun.os.patch.level` property without throwing an AccessControlException.

Applets have security restrictions imposed on.

The only thing you can do is to read on signed applets and policy files for applets

Comment: This is true but perhaps their is another way to determine the service pack level other than trying to read the 'sun.os.patch.level' property?